# VBA: error message in r.Copy output_sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i got a problem when trying to copy my data from sheet1 into sheet2. Got an input from a path in a directory and inserting the data in sheet1. I only need the defined cells in certain rows as you can see in my code. I got a predefined header for each column in sheet2 so the columns is coherent.
The problem is that my r.Copy output_sheet code line gives me an error like "this action isnt available with more selections" (translated the error message from my language so dont know what exactly is written in english)

How can i fix this problem so i can make the data input, copy the specific cells and paste them in sheet2?

```
Sub call_copy_sub_ranges()

    Worksheets("Ark2").[A1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[B1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[C1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[D1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[E1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[F1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[G1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[H1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[I1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[J1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[K1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[L1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[M1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[N1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[O1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[P1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[Q1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[R1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[S1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[T1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[U1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[V1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[W1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[X1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[Y1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[Z1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AA1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AB1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AC1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AD1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AE1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AF1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AG1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AH1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AI1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AJ1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AK1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AL1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AM1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AN1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AO1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AP1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AQ1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AR1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AS1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AT1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AU1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AV1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AW1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AX1].Value = "'headerName"
    Worksheets("Ark2").[AY1].Value = "'headerName"

    Dim super_range As Range
    Set super_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Columns("A:EI")

    Dim output_sheet As Worksheet
    Set output_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2")

    copy_sub_ranges super_range, output_sheet

End Sub


Sub copy_sub_ranges(ByVal super_range As Range, ByVal output_sheet As Worksheet)

    Dim r As Range

    Set r = super_range.Range("S2:S3")
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BF7:BF8"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BG7:BG8"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BH7:BH8"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BI9:BI10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BJ9:BJ10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BK9:BK10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BL9:BL10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BM9:BM10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BN9:BN10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BO9:BO10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BP9:BP10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BQ9:BQ10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BR9:BR10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BS9:BR10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BT9:BT10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BU9:BU10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BV9:BV10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BW9:BW10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BX9:BX10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BY9:BY10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("BZ9:BZ10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CA9:CA10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CB9:CB10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CC9:CC10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CD9:CD9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CE9:CE9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CF9:CF9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CG9:CG9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CH9:CH9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CI9:CI9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CJ9:CJ9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CK9:CK9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CL9:CL9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CM9:CM9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CN9:CN9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CO9:CO9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CP9:CP9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CQ9:CQ9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CR9:CR10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CS9:CS10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CT9:CT9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CU9:CU9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CV9:CV9"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CW9:CW10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("CX10:CX10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("EE9:EE10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("EF9:EF10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("EG9:EG10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("EH9:EH10"))
    Set r = Union(r, super_range.Range("EI9:EI10"))

    Dim offset As Long
    If IsEmpty(output_sheet.Range("A1").Text) Then offset = 0 Else offset = 1

    r.Copy output_sheet.Cells(output_sheet.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(offset, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can reference multiple ranges from a single call to the `Range` method: `Set r = super_range.Range("S2:S3,BF7:BF8")` etc. You can also set the same value on multiple cells in the range: `Worksheets("Ark2").Range("A1,B1").Value = "headerName".

Comment: For reference, the error in English is **That command cannot be used on multiple selections.** I guess the only way to work around this is to write a new `Sub` that iterates over the subranges in the `Range.Areas` property, and copy each one individually relative to the destination range.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, were a bit stuck, so I'm very happy for the help:)

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT the problem is Excel doesn't support copying/pasting from a range that has multiple areas, like this:

```vb
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range( _
    "S2:S3," & _
    "BF7:BH8," & _
    "BI9:CC10," & _
    "CD9:CQ9," & _
    "CR9:CS10," & _
    "CT9:CV9," & _
    "CW9:CX10," & _
    "EE9:EI10" _
)
```

We can get each of the subranges from the `Areas` property:

```vb
Dim subrange As Range
For Each subrange In rng.Areas
    Debug.Print subrange.Address
Next
```

So we can write a method that:

- if there is only one area in the range, it will copy the entire range to the destination
- if there is more than one area, it will copy each area individually to the destination; not directly to the destination, but offset the same number of rows and columns from the destination as the area is from the worksheet.

```vb
Sub CopyMultiRange(src As Range, dest As Range)
If src.Areas.Count = 1 Then
    src.Copy dest
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim subrange As Range
For Each subrange In src.Areas
    CopyMultiRange subrange, dest.Offset(subrange.Row - 1, subrange.Column - 1)
Next
End Sub
```

And you can call it like this:

```vb
CopyMultiRange rng, Worksheets("Ark2").Range("A1")
```

Notes:

- Ideally we'd want to copy each subrange to the destination relative to the offset the subrange is from the source range. However, I didn't find any way to get the minimum top/left corner of all the subranges. So the offset is calculated off the worksheet, using the `Row` and `Column` properties.
- To account for the possibility that a range might have multiple levels of subranges, the method calls itself. I haven't checked that this can actually happen.

Comment: Note this copies for example cell S2 to cell T3 on Ark2 but I read the requirement as aligning the copied ranges into 2 rows under the heading col A to AY1. so S to A, BF to B etc

Comment: @CDP1802 when i make a macro button by going to developer and making it manually, it disappear when i make a new data input in sheet1, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

As Zev said, copy each range individually

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub call_copy_sub_ranges()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1")
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2")

    Dim ar
    ar = Array("HeaderA", "HeaderB", "HeaderC", "HeaderD", "HeaderE", _
    "HeaderF", "HeaderG", "HeaderH", "HeaderI", "HeaderJ", "HeaderK", _
    "HeaderL", "HeaderM", "HeaderN", "HeaderO", "HeaderP", "HeaderQ", _
    "HeaderR", "HeaderS", "HeaderT", "HeaderU", "HeaderV", "HeaderW", _
    "HeaderX", "HeaderY", "HeaderZ", "HeaderAA", "HeaderAB", "HeaderAC", _
    "HeaderAD", "HeaderAE", "HeaderAF", "HeaderAG", "HeaderAH", "HeaderAI", _
    "HeaderAJ", "HeaderAK", "HeaderAL", "HeaderAM", "HeaderAN", "HeaderAO", _
    "HeaderAP", "HeaderAQ", "HeaderAR", "HeaderAS", "HeaderAT", "HeaderAU", _
    "HeaderAV", "HeaderAW", "HeaderAX", "HeaderAY")
       
    wsOut.Range("A1:AY1").Value = ar
    copy_sub_ranges ws1, wsOut
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub


Sub copy_sub_ranges(ByVal ws1 As Worksheet, ByVal wsOut As Worksheet)

    Dim rng As Range, rngOut As Range, ar, s
    ar = Array("S2:S3", "BF7:BH8", "BI9:CC10", _
                "CD9:CQ9", "CR9:CS10", "CT9:CV9", "CW9:CW10", "CX10", "EE9:EI10")
                   
    ' target
    Set rngOut = wsOut.Cells(wsOut.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    If Not IsEmpty(wsOut.Range("A1").Text) Then
       Set rngOut = rngOut.offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    For Each s In ar
       Set rng = ws1.Range(s)
       Debug.Print rng.Address, rngOut.Address
       
       rng.Copy rngOut
       Set rngOut = rngOut.offset(0, rng.Columns.Count)
    Next

    ' underline
    Set rng = wsOut.Cells(wsOut.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    With rng.Resize(1, rngOut.Column - 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I works so perfect. How can i auto adjust alle the headers and data which gets pasted in sheet2? Some of the cells has "#####" as there isnt enough space

Comment: @Anonymous Add `wsOut.Columns("A:AY").AutoFit` at the end (before `msgbox "Done"`)

Comment: You have made my day! Thanks for the help, im a rookie to VBA. Have a great day:)

Comment: This isn't quite what I was suggesting, nor does it actually answer the problem, because you're creating the ranges as single-area ranges based on the array, not using a multi-area array as in the question. The `Range` object exposes an `Areas` property, which returns the subranges of a specified `Range` object; you could iterate over `Areas`, calculate the offset of each subrange from the original range, and paste the subrange onto the destination range with the same offset.

Comment: Is it possible to code a Macro button in sheet1 so i just need to click instead of press F5. Or should i just go to developer in the menu line and make one myself? If the macro button isnt made in the code, then how can it stay in sheet1 when i make a new data input? Hope you can understand the question:) TIA

Comment: Zev Spitz, I know you thought of something different, but the answer from CDP1802 works perfectly:)

Comment: @CDP1802, dont know how to do that:(

Comment: @CDP1802, Thanks. I promise this will be my last question; How can i get a "underline" or bold line after every two rows in sheet2? So every time i paste the two rows copied from sheet1, it makes a line under the second row.

Comment: @ZebSpitz What do you mean by 'the original range' ?

Comment: @CDP1802, you are the man. Thanks a lot. Got another question haha, but maybe i can write to you personally as you seem to understand VBA quite well?

Comment: @CDP1802 See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66351106/111794).

Comment: @CDP1802 ; Made a new question and would love the help again:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366714/vba-text-recognition-copy-specific-columns-from-sheet1-to-sheet2