# VBA: text recognition - copy specific columns from sheet1 to sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

a kind soul made me this code for another question i asked. But im thinking about text recognition. So i got a data input in sheet1, there is some headers for each column in the data input, and i want to sort by specific header names, copy them, and paste the two rows of the columns which header matches my keywords, in sheet2. Pasting the data in sheet2, should be at the first two lines available, like here in my code already. Really want to keep most of the code as possible and then maybe only change the sub where i copy the two rows in a specific range. Would appreciate the help:)

```
Option Explicit

Sub call_copy_sub_ranges()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1")
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2")

    Dim ar
    ar = Array("HeaderA", "HeaderB", "HeaderC", "HeaderD", "HeaderE", _
    "HeaderF", "HeaderG", "HeaderH", "HeaderI", "HeaderJ", "HeaderK", _
    "HeaderL", "HeaderM", "HeaderN", "HeaderO", "HeaderP", "HeaderQ", _
    "HeaderR", "HeaderS", "HeaderT", "HeaderU", "HeaderV", "HeaderW", _
    "HeaderX", "HeaderY", "HeaderZ", "HeaderAA", "HeaderAB", "HeaderAC", _
    "HeaderAD", "HeaderAE", "HeaderAF", "HeaderAG", "HeaderAH", "HeaderAI", _
    "HeaderAJ", "HeaderAK", "HeaderAL", "HeaderAM", "HeaderAN", "HeaderAO", _
    "HeaderAP", "HeaderAQ", "HeaderAR", "HeaderAS", "HeaderAT", "HeaderAU", _
    "HeaderAV", "HeaderAW", "HeaderAX", "HeaderAY")
   
    wsOut.Range("A1:AY1").Value = ar
    copy_sub_ranges ws1, wsOut
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub


Sub copy_sub_ranges(ByVal ws1 As Worksheet, ByVal wsOut As Worksheet)

    Dim rng As Range, rngOut As Range, ar, s
    ar = Array("S2:S3", "BF7:BH8", "BI9:CC10", _
    "CD9:CQ9", "CR9:CS10", "CT9:CV9", "CW9:CW10", "CX10", "EE9:EI10")
               
    ' target
    Set rngOut = wsOut.Cells(wsOut.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    If Not IsEmpty(wsOut.Range("A1").Text) Then
        Set rngOut = rngOut.offset(1, 0)
    End If

    For Each s In ar
        Set rng = ws1.Range(s)
        Debug.Print rng.Address, rngOut.Address
   
        rng.Copy rngOut
        Set rngOut = rngOut.offset(0, rng.Columns.Count)
    Next

    ' underline
    Set rng = wsOut.Cells(wsOut.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    With rng.Resize(1, rngOut.Column - 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. _Thinking about text recognition_ please clarify what this has to do with your question. 2. _Really want to keep most of the code as possible and then maybe only change the sub where i copy the two rows in a specific range._ That puts some extreme limitations on a possible solution.

Comment: 3. It would be far more useful to give some sample data inside your question, and thus give some idea of the structure of your input worksheet; then to expect people to parse someone else's code in order to understand said structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute an SQL statement on your worksheet, or on a range within the worksheet. This would allow you to trivially select only specific columns, and sort by specific columns.

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects**; choose the latest version (usually 6.1).

Then you could write code similar to the following:

```vb
Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT HeaderA, HeaderG, HeaderP "  & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    "ORDER BY HeaderQ, HeaderR"

' If your data is only in a specific range, you can limit to that range:
'sql = _
'    "SELECT HeaderA, HeaderG, HeaderP "  & _
'    "FROM [Sheet1$B5:AA17] " & _
'    "ORDER BY HeaderQ, HeaderR"

Const filepath As String = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Note that there's nothing preventing you from using an array of strings as the selected columns, or as the sort fields; use the `Join` function to combine the field names into a comma-separated string:

```vb
Dim fieldnames() As String
fieldnames = Array("HeaderB", "HeaderC", "HeaderD")

Dim sortnames() As String
sortnames = Array("HeaderM", "HeaderN", "HeaderO")

sql = _
    "SELECT " & Join(fieldnames, ", ") & " " & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    "ORDER BY " & Join(sortnames, ", ")
```

`fieldnames` and `sortnames` could be populated from different cells:

```vb
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
fieldnames = Array(sheet.Range("A1").Value, sheet.Range("B1").Value))
```

Comment: So this code checks the name of the header and copy it? So lets say the header i want to copy is in A1 and A3, and the A1 header is "name" and the A3 header is "age". Then how is it possible to write, when this text is in a cell, copy it from sheet1 and paste it in sheet2

Comment: @Anonymous Updated.